# Is there limit to access youtube's get_video_info from single IP

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, limit, restrictions

i am developing a online youtube video downloader in php . but i am afraid of blocking my Server Ip by youtube.

is there such restrictions by youtube ?
and if yes thenn how much requests i can do to youtube in single day ?

Answer (score -1):

This information is available here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota

Comment: Hello Mike .Actually that is for youtube api i am not using api.

Answer (score -3):

If you are downloading/re-distributing YouTube audio-visual content you are directly in violation of YouTube's Terms of Service. No matter the number of requests, take a look at these points mentioned in the [YouTube Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms?hl=en):

> 10. access any portion of any YouTube audiovisual content by any means other than use of a YouTube player or other video player expressly
>       authorized by YouTube;
> 11. store copies of YouTube audiovisual content;

In any case, downloading YouTube videos or developing a tool to do so are definitely counted as Copyright infringement. To make it more clear, read this under Section III of the link provided above:

> 1. **Compliance with Laws**. You are responsible for complying with all applicable laws, rules and regulations, all third-party rights and
>      all YouTube policies. You shall not use the YouTube API in a manner
>      that violates such laws, rules and regulations, third parties' rights
>      or any YouTube policies or in a manner that is deceptive, unethical,
>      false or misleading. For avoidance of doubt, You shall not distribute
>      or provide access to applications You develop in contravention of U.S.
>      export control or trade laws.

Hence, developing such a tool will hold you in violation of the YouTube ToS and (action including but not limited to) definitely get your IP blocked.

However, if you plan on making a different tool that provides legal usage of the API, here is a [Quota cost calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) that can be used to determine what kind of requests can be made and how much they'll cost. And the link provided by Mike shows the daily allowance of the YouTube API.

Comment: Read the ToS again - if you have permission from the content owner, you may download and redistribute the content.